# What are the values of $(a,b)$ so that this weakly stationary process is well-defined?

Tags: stochastic-processes, time-series

I'm solving this exercise from previous final exam of Time Series. Because tomorrow is my exam, it's too late for me to send the professor an email.

[image]

Could you explain on what does it mean for $X$ to be well-defined in this case? I think the question have mentioned that $X$ is weakly stationary process and thus *already* well-defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an ARMA(1,1) process. I think the question b) requires you to find the coefficient values consistent with stationarity. You can write this as

$$(1-aB)X_t=(1-bB)\epsilon_t$$

As explained e.g. [here](http://matthieustigler.github.io/Lectures/Lect2ARMA.pdf) this is stationary if the roots of $P(z)=1-az$ lie outside the unit circle. The roots solve

$$P(z)=0$$

or

$$1-az=0$$

or

$$z=\frac{1}{a}$$

So you need $|\frac{1}{a}| > 1$ or $-1<a<1$.